# How can I detect the java runtime in Mac OS X?

Tags: java, macos, cocoa

Our cocoa app may invoke a module that is written with Java, but the Java environment is not always installed on Mac OS X, especially in Mac OS 10.7.

So, how can I detect whether the java runtime exists or not before invoking the module with cocoa?

Comment: Mac OS X should prompt the user to install Java if an app tries to use it.

Answer (score 4):

Try checking the value of `exec /usr/libexec/java_home` (note the backticks! not apostrophes!).  This will give you the location of the current Java installation, and should include the version number.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the command:

```
$ java -version

$ which java
```